# Change a listview row background color

Tags: android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer activity. The default selected item color is blue, I want to change it to green.

Here is my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="#19A3A3"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:textColor="@color/primary_material_dark"
tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
/>
```

I created the background.xml in drawables:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_hovered="true" android:state_activated="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/material_blue_grey_900" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

When I execute the app, the selected listview item still is blue.

Any ideia to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:state_hovered="true" android:state_activated="true"
      android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">...</item>
```

When you add all the states like above, it actually means that the item is only selected if every single statement resolves to `true`. In other words, you can think of the states as being `AND`'ed. You seem to have assumed they are `OR`'ed.

Differently said, what you currently have reads as: "select this item if (and only if) the element is hovered AND activated AND checked AND pressed."

Try setting only one state first to confirm my statement (or even none):

```
<item android:state_activated="true">...</item>
```

If you want the same behaviour for the other states, you're going to have to add a new `<item>...</item>` entry for every single one.